# WCF message encryption

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Is it possible to host a WCF service in IIS, access it over HTTP and have the message body encrypted using a wsHttpBinding configuration?

Comment: yes - if i can dig up a working example in time, will post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any protocol that can support message security and the WS-Security standard will be capable of encrypting your messages - it's actually the default setting, too.

See [Message Security in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx) for more information, and for hints about how to secure your messages using a Windows credential or a X.509 certificate as the "shared secret" between client and server to ensure encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Check this page from MSDN on how to configure your bindings to do what you need:

[MSDN - Web Service Protocols Supported by System-Provided Interoperability Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730294.aspx)